# What is the correct way to convert this to a date time in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have an asp.net-mvc site that is reading a string field from a sharepoint site and i get a string

```
var stringDate = "3/11/2016 12:05:00 AM"
```

I was told the time is in **Eastern Standard Time**.  I try to convert to a date using:

```
 var date = DateTime.Parse(stringDate);
```

and I think display it using this format:

```
<%= Model.Date.ToString("MMM dd HH:mm")
```

When I run this on a machine in the US, I get

```
Mar 14 00:05 (which is what i want to display)
```

but when i run the same code on a machine in London, I get:

```
Mar 14 05:05 (which is NOT what i want to display)
```

What is the right way to show the date in Eastern Standard Time regardless of where the server is hosted?

Comment: Time in London is (NY Time + 5 hours), so it looks quite reasonable.

Comment: but i want to display the Eastern Standard Time where ever i run the site from

Comment: See my extended answer: get the UTC from that remote server and subtract 5 hours. Best regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question was changed after my first answer was provided so here's a different answer to the changed question.

The way to keep datetime straight globally is to always capture and persist datetime values in UTC and then translate to the context time zone for use/display.

In this case adding 5 hours to the provided, parsed value gives us UTC if Daylight Savings Time is ignored. Any variations in offset due to Daylight Savings Time must be taken account and the offset adjusted accordingly when determining UTC.

```
DateTime dtInUTC = DateTime.ParseExact("3/11/2016 12:05:00 AM", "M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).AddHours(5); // the source string is expressed in ET
Console.WriteLine(ToLocalTime(dtInUTC, "Eastern Standard Time")); // for ET
Console.WriteLine(ToLocalTime(dtInUTC, "GMT Standard Time")); // for GMT
```

This is what I use to convert timezone for context:

```
private static DateTime ToLocalTime(DateTime utcDateTime, string tzId) {
   TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(tzId);
   return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcDateTime, tz);
}
```

Normally I'd keep the user time zone with a given user's profile, not hardcode it, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know it's in Eastern Time it's important to retain that truth in the parsed value.  I'd append the -5 offset and parse the provided string.  Once you parse it as ET explicitly the following

```
DateTime t = DateTime.ParseExact("3/11/2016 12:05:00 AM -05:00", 
    "M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(t.ToUniversalTime());
```

...results in this:

```
3/11/2016 5:05:00 AM
```

I suspect the "flexible" behavior you describe in your question is the result of the following value apparently being the default in the Parse method: `AssumeLocal`

Here is an excerpt of the relevant DateTime.ParseExact doc, [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131038(v=vs.110).aspx).

> **AssumeLocal:** Specifies that if s lacks any time zone information, it is assumed to represent a local time. Unless the
>   DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal flag is present, the Kind property of
>   the returned DateTime value is set to DateTimeKind.Local.
>
> **AssumeUniversal:** Specifies that if s lacks any time zone information,
>   it is assumed to represent UTC. Unless the
>   DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal flag is present, the method converts
>   the returned DateTime value from UTC to local time and sets its Kind
>   property to DateTimeKind.Local.

Daylight Savings Time is a problem, but not if you capture the current offset and append it appropriately in the parsing instead of just hardcoding -05:00.

Comment: see my updated question.  I want to show the value in Eastern Standard time

Comment: DST can only be computed this way if you are displaying the current time.

Comment: @Jeff: not exactly, as long as the offset associated with the value being parsed is known/used - nothing to do with current time

Comment: @Tahbaza At the end of your answer you specify current offset, which only works if converting current time. I only point it out because this is a typical pitfall when displaying DST.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on how the time string was generated on the remote server. For example, if the string represents the local time on that remote server, then you can try to `ParseExact()` and `ToUniversalTime()` to get GMT (Greenwich Mean Time, aka UTC), then subtract 5 hours to get EST (this operation should be performed on the remote server):

```
DateTime _ny = 
DateTime.ParseExact("3/11/2016 12:05:00 AM", 
"mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss UTC", 
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToUniversalTime().AddHours(-5);
```

*Note*: Time in NY City is EST (UTC-05:00, or GMT-05:00).

The solution could be further extended by using `TimeZoneInfo` class to calculate the offset (re: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo(v=vs.110).aspx). Pertinent to your question, US Eastern Standard Time ID is 720 (UTC-05:00) (re: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg154758.aspx).

Also, be aware that if you read the data from remote server, then you have to adjust the solution pertinent to that server time zone. Once I was facing similar problem, caused by my real-time web app residing at remote Azure cloud server, so I used the similar solution (re: Listing 10, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/884183/enRoute-Real-time-NY-City-Bus-Tracking-Web-App)

```
/// <summary>
/// Get the accurate NY Time value
/// </summary>
/// <returns>DateTime</returns>
protected DateTime GetTimeNYC()
{
    try { return DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().AddHours(_offsetHour); }
    catch { throw; }
}
```

Hope this may help.

Comment: This doesn't take daylight savings time into account.

Comment: @Jeff: that's right, but daylight saving was not included in the requirement; otherwise, the solution can be further extended per additional requirements. Best regards,

Comment: you changed the original string around from my question.  I don't have UTC in my string

Comment: This seems to be backward - the original text is already in NY time. So you should be subtracting 5 hours to get UTC.

Comment: At the core of the solution is to calculate the time offset between the EST and the local: so, it takes into account the local time and difference between time zone by calculating UTC and subtracting 5 hours. Best regards,

Comment: @Enigmativity: that's right, it should be vice versa. Thanks and regards,

Comment: @Jeff Thanks and regards,

Comment: i am still confused why you put UTC in the original string.  In my case i have AM and that time is the eastern standard time

Comment: @AlexBell - My point was that in your string you have UTC - `"3/11/2016 12:05:00 UTC"`, but this is the time in NY time. The `"UTC"` shouldn't be there.

Comment: OK, let's put it in other words: you need to Parse the string (in whatever format using whatever method) to get the Greenwich Mean Time (GMT), then subtract 5 hours. There are several ways to accomplish that, depends on HOW the string was generated on the remote server. In my case (plz see the extended answer) I was using DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().AddHours(_offsetHour), i.e GMT offsetted by 5 hrs. It may work in your case either. Best regards,

Answer (score -1):

Try it:

```
DateTime _dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "your format",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I hope it help.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `DateTimeOffset` for this as it has been built to deal with timezones properly.

Then you can do this:

```
var stringDate = "3/11/2016 12:05:00 AM";

var value =
    DateTimeOffset
        .ParseExact(
            stringDate + "-05:00",
            "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss ttzzz",
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"));
```

This will **always** parse your input in EST (`"-05:00"`) time.

When I write the value to the console you get this:

```
2016/03/11 00:05:00 -05:00
```

It just knows about the time zone. There's no confusion here.

Comment: if i do this, i get an error: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Comment: @leora - I ran the code in my answer before posting and it worked fine. Did you run my code exactly as is?